# Difference between Assemblies Framework and Extensions

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

What is difference between `Assemblies Framework` and `Assemblies Extensions` in `Add Reference Dialog` box?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(VS.ReferenceManager);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true) (hit the `?` in your `Add Reference` dialog):

> The Assemblies tab consists of two sub-tabs:
>
> 1.Framework lists all assemblies that **constitute the targeted Framework**.
>
> 2.Extensions lists all assemblies that **external vendors** of components and controls have developed to extend the targeted Framework. Depending on the purpose of the user application, it might need these assemblies.

So the first is just what Microsoft delivers for that .NET version, the other one contains all others.

Comment: Both has System.code.dll. then what is difference between them

Comment: @KapilDave: I only have `System.Core` in the first, not the second.

Comment: I have checked twice, Extensions and Framework, both display system.core.

Comment: @KapilDave: maybe some bug, maybe they reside in another place than the GAC and that's why it is picked up. Actually I don't know.

Comment: Note only System.Core but many other .dll also list down in Extensions Tab which are already list down in Framework Tab. Interesting thing is from both tab .dll point same path e.g. System.Core path display in tool tip is : For Framwork and Extensions tab- C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5

Comment: my current configuration is : Windows 8 64 bits + visual studio 2013 express edition

Comment: @ Patrick Hofman, Kindly create WebSite, Not WebProject, then check, in both tab, FrameWork and Extention Tab, you will find System.Core dll. I think this is not a bug.